# Bundle a React component library with Rollup.js v1

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, rollupjs

I'm working on an Open Source D3/React component library and I'm trying to bundle the library using Rollup.js to offer code splitting, three shaking, etc.

The library is already published in [GitHub](https://github.com/davegomez/silky-charts) and [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/silky-charts) and you can check a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ykwp5pnxkj) using the library for a reference in case you want to try it.

Next I'm gonna try to highlight the different issues I'm experiencing with this bundle.

The library has already been tested using the code directly in a project and it works perfectly, so the problem is with the bundle and I assume that I'm doing something wrong with the [Rollup.js configuration file](https://github.com/davegomez/silky-charts/blob/master/rollup.config.js) in my project.

```
import { readdirSync } from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import replace from 'rollup-plugin-replace';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';

const CODES = [
  'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED',
  'MISSING_GLOBAL_NAME',
  'CIRCULAR_DEPENDENCY',
];

const getChunks = URI =>
  readdirSync(path.resolve(URI))
    .filter(x => x.includes('.js'))
    .reduce((a, c) => ({ ...a, [c.replace('.js', '')]: `src/${c}` }), {});

const discardWarning = warning => {
  if (CODES.includes(warning.code)) {
    return;
  }

  console.error(warning);
};

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

const plugins = [
  external(),
  babel({
    exclude: 'node_modules/**',
  }),
  resolve(),
  replace({ 'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(env) }),
  commonjs(),
  env === 'production' && terser(),
];

export default [
  {
    onwarn: discardWarning,
    input: 'src/index.js',
    output: {
      esModule: false,
      file: 'umd/silky-charts.js',
      format: 'umd',
      name: 'silkyCharts',
    },
    plugins,
  },
  {
    onwarn: discardWarning,
    input: getChunks('src'),
    output: [
      { dir: 'esm', format: 'esm', sourcemap: true },
      { dir: 'cjs', format: 'cjs', sourcemap: true },
    ],
    plugins,
  },
];
```

### The Errors

When I try to use the library using the production bundle (which is the default) directly from the NPM package I got the following error coming from one of the chunks `node_modules/silky-charts/esm/chunk-501b9e58.js:5833`

```
TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...) is not a function
```

---

If I stead use the development bundle I get a different error:

```
Failed to compile
../silky-charts/esm/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in '/Users/davidg/Development/personal/silky-charts/esm'
```

This error force me to install React, ReactDOM, and styled-components as devDependencies in the project for the library have access to these projects code.

---

After installing the devDependencies the error I get is the next one:

```
Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.
```

I already [filled an issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14721) in the React project page and according to them this is not a React issue but maybe a Webpack's since is usual to find this error when you have to install React in both the project and the library and Webpack finds there is two instances of React, and I kind of agree since the error varies depending on bundle type or the way the importer project is run as you can see in the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ykwp5pnxkj).

---

I hope you can help me to spot the error in the Rollup configuration file and if you feel like doing a PR in the project event better .

Comment: Any solution on this?

Comment: I already fixed it. Gonna publish the changes as soon as I have time.